# WebView loads URL 10 times slower than phone's Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I've been trying to figure this one out for quite a while, and yet haven't found a solution.

Inside my app I'm extracting a website's HTML through an invisible WebView component. I do not need to view the website, just get the html it loads. The website uses JavaScript to load all of its content, and therefore I need a full web renderer in order to execute that JavaScript. In its current form, I'm overriding the WebViewClient's onPageFinished method to inject JavaScript that dumps the html into a JavaScriptInterface which then processes it.

My main issue here is that when I load this URL inside my app it would take about 8 seconds, whereas loading the exact same URL in the phone's chrome browser it takes less than a second. Any suggestions as to what might be the problem?

If it could be of any help, the JavaScript that gets executed stores a cookie inside the WebView, and then tries to retrieve it, and only if it finds said cookie (which has a short expiration time) it would load the site's HTML. In this case it actually loads data formatted with JSON (about 370k characters).

Relevant WebView code:

```
private void initWebView(View view) {
    class JSInterface{
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void processHTML(String scheduleJSONResponse){
            if(scheduleJSONResponse.length() > 10000){
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Finished loading JSON");
            }
        }
    }
    webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_movies_web_view);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(), "Android");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Page finished loading");
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.Android.processHTML(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].textContent);");
        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}
```

As for why I check that the length is more than 10k characters: Sometimes onPageFinished would get called more than once, with the first call being before the JavaScript is executed, and so I get HTML containing the script to be executed which isn't what I need.

Thanks in advance for any help!

---

A logcat to demonstrate the issue:

```
08-18 22:32:23.623 26238-26238/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1e4dc08f time:502735009
08-18 22:32:23.638 26238-26238/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 26238
08-18 22:32:31.336 26238-26238/com.michaelsvit.kolnoa D/MovieGridFragment: Page finished loading
```

Current code after simplifying it:

```
private void initWebView(View view) {
    class JSInterface{
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void processHTML(String scheduleJSONResponse){
            if(scheduleJSONResponse.length() > 10000){
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Finished loading JSON");
            }
        }
    }
    webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_movies_web_view);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(), "Android");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Page finished loading");
            //webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.Android.processHTML(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].textContent);");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is it 8 seconds before onPageFinished is invoked?

Comment: @greenaps It is 8 seconds from the point which I call webView.loadUrl to the point I get "Page finished loading" through onPageFinished

Comment: `the JavaScript that gets executed stores a cookie `. But there is no javascript executed before onPageFinished is invoked is it? And otherwise that code is missing.

Comment: @greenapps It is JavaScript that is embedded in this particular website, not code that I wrote.

Comment: Please confirm or deny: `But there is no javascript executed before onPageFinished is invoked is it?`.

Comment: `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(), "Android");
 `. Cant you execute these statement after onPageFinished is invoked?

Comment: @greenapps There is, and as I said, it is embedded with the website. If you'd try to extract the HTML before said JavaScript is executed, all you'd get is a couple of HTML tags and a script to be executed. What you suggested would be impossible as it has to be able to execute the embedded JavaScript.

Comment: Ok. That i had forgotten. Sorry. You have an internet url so we can test?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121263/discussion-between-michael-svit-and-greenapps).

Comment: `through an invisible WebView component.`. What when it is visible? No chat.

Comment: @greenapps The specific URL is www.yesplanet.co.il/presentationsJSON. The only use I have of said WebView is to process the website with its JavaScript so that I would retrieve its HTML when it is done. I set the WebView's visible property to false when setting it up via XML.

Comment: Try once without setting the javascript interface. I tried that url and it is nearly instantanuous. Javascript enabled only for the WebViewCient.

Comment: @greenapps I believe what you're getting is what I described as a "false positive". Some of the times onPageFinished would get called twice, with the first time being before the page's JavaScript gets executed. If you would keep waiting, it would then get called a second time, after JS execution. As I noted, this is why I added a length check on the interface's method.

Comment: ??? I see the complets long page. The same as when using a browser. And then myOnPgeFinished toast.. What else is there more? That was on 5.1. On a 4.4 device nothing happens.

Comment: @greenapps But then how would I extract the JSON text if I do not set this JS interface? I do not know of any other method to do this.

Comment: And even if I remove the interface code, I'm still getting this slow performance. I will update the question with a logcat.

Comment: It was just something to test out to see where your delay comes from. So did you try? Does it make any difference? You can set the interface in onPageFinished. Why not?

Comment: I sugest you make a new project or a new activity with a webview to just load the url. You will see that it goes quick.

Comment: What kind of device and version are you testing on? Use different devices.

Comment: @greenapps Current device is a Galaxy S4 with a custom ROM with Android 5.1. I also tried timing it with an AVD, and it seems the delay is around 2 seconds or less with it. I will try testing on another physical device.

Comment: If you just need the HTML, why bother with the webview?? Just request that page with a HTTP Client of your choice and get the returned string (content of the page).

Comment: OP already explained twice that the html is generated by the javascript in the page. HTTP components do not execute javascript like browsers do.

Comment: @VSG24 as greenapps noted, an HTTP client such as OkHttp would just retrieve the HTML document before JS execution, which is basically useless to me since that JS generates all of the content. I do not know any other method to extract the HTML after JS execution.

Comment: @greenapps I have tested another physical device now, an LG G4 running Android 6.0. First run of the code produced a 20 second delay until the whole page was loaded, and subsequent calls seem to have a 3-4 second delay, as opposed to ~8 seconds on my Galaxy S4.

Comment: Can you confirm that `{"sites":[{"sn":"×™×¡` is the start of the page and `"IMAX","VIP",null,"4DX"]}` the end? Well i get this with a WebView within half a second. On a cheap 6.0 phone.

Comment: But did you try already with another webview in another activity? And did you try with a visible webview? I suggested that before but you did not react.

Comment: It is! This is very strange then. Could you share your code please so that I could compare it with my own? I obviously haven't shared everything, just the relevant (or at least, what I believe is relevant) code, so maybe I missed something. I haven't tried it with a  visible WebView or in an empty activity. I will try it and update with results.

Comment: It is exactly your code but removed the JSInterface and the call to it. `webview1.loadUrl(url);`.

Comment: @greenapps Good news! I tried your suggestion of changing the WebView to be visible again, and as soon as I did that it started working instantly!! Now do you have a suggestion as to how I could work around it? I do not want the WebView to be visible at all. It is just there as a tool to extract the HTML. Thank you so much for your help :)! Please add an answer so I could mark it.

Comment: Try to change the layout. Move the place of the webview so only a few lines are visible. I think a few pixels should stay visible. Or otherwise make the webview invisible in onPageFinished. Load a nice picture in it before so the user is distracted during the load ;-).

Comment: @MichaelSvit Did you happen to find a solution without making the WebView visible?  I have a similar situation, with a WebView embedded in a service.

Comment: @MichaelSvit Nevermind, that was easy!   I just made the WebView 1x1 pixel and that did the trick. :

Comment: @HolySamosa That was essentially my solution as well ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  through an invisible WebView component..
```

What when it is visible?

Try it!

Comment: I cannot explain why, but turning the WebView visible again solves this issue. Perhaps it has to do with run-time optimization that slows invisible components? Anyways, thanks again!

Comment: Think that the scheduler gives lower priority to processes in the background.